# get file properties like artist and album name in php

Tags: php, file

Does any one know any php function which can be used to get properties of music files such as album, artist, length etc.

I know functions like filetype($file), fileperms($file), fileowner($file) and filegroup($file) but they don't exactly do what I want,

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You need an mp3 parser class for that. Google it. They're out there.

Answer (score 2):

If your file formats are mp3 you can use [getID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/). getID3() is a PHP script that extracts useful information from MP3s & other multimedia file formats.